# Mariadb 10 slave won't sync

Tags: mysql, slave

Slave won't sync with master No Error everything is fine..

```
show all slaves status 

                 Connection_name: godzilla
              Slave_SQL_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
                  Master_User: slavexxx
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 10
              Master_Log_File: CentOS-72-64-minimal-bin.000005
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 12457
               Relay_Log_File: CentOS-72-64-minimal-relay-bin-euro@002dslot@002ecom.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 1102
        Relay_Master_Log_File: CentOS-72-64-minimal-bin.000005
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 12457
              Relay_Log_Space: 1436
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 6
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                   Using_Gtid: No
                  Gtid_IO_Pos:
         Retried_transactions: 0
           Max_relay_log_size: 1073741824
         Executed_log_entries: 679
    Slave_received_heartbeats: 0
       Slave_heartbeat_period: 1800.000
               Gtid_Slave_Pos: 0-5-276329635
```

On my slave server i have another 5 Databases with Different Master IP its working fine today i want to connect new master and slave won't sync No Errors ...

[image]

[image]

This [steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql) i use to setup SLAVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after 2 days i find the problem 
On slave my.cnf i remove this option

```
[mysqld]
#gtid-ignore-duplicates=ON
```